# How to Configure Jenkins Gerrit Trigger Plugin to do a premerge

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration, gerrit

I am stuck for some hours now, trying out how to configure my Jenkins verification-job to do the following:

- Be triggered by a Gerrit event of "Patchset Created" (works)
- Then fetch the specific change from Gerrit (works)
- Merge/rebase the current change to the most recent origin/master (does not work)
- Perform the build (works)

As you can see I don't know how to configure the Job to make sure, the origin/master branch is allways the very recent version, when I configure the Trigger Plugin according to the documentation, using **GERRIT_REFSPEC** and **GERRIT_BRANCH**.

As our project has several branches, I do not want to fetch them all in the job, just to be able to do a merge on the most recent origin/master. I tried to do some concatenated Refspec like origin/master:refs/remotes/origin/master,GERRIT_BRANCH but this did not work. In other words, what I would like to do is:

Be triggered by the change, fetch the change, fetch the most recent master, do the rebase/merge and then build.
Can this be done with the plugin's form, or would I have to do some manual GIT commandline acrobatics?

Answer (score 0):

Gerrit-Trigger plugin is not intended for merging other branches -
should use your won script for that (which you can trigger as a different Jenkins-job).

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
Actually I was not precise in my question, as I see now. Sorry for that!

What it wanted to do was to combine Gerrit Trigger Plugin and Git Plugin. The latter one has an "Additional Behaviour" called "Merge before build". What I failed at, was configuring the Git Plugin accordingly to make use of the additional behaviour.

Comment: I don't really understand why you merge (or rebase) files in your build-environment - you basically want to build a specific commit that is already in your repository, and not something that was merged unpredictably. Let the plugin get the specific commit from the repository, and build it.